# PHP array to echo javascript array that I can access?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php array called $user.

At the minute I am getting the variables across to javascript by manually adding them like so.

```
var username = ' . $user['username'] . ';
```

And so on is there a way I can make php echo a javascript array that I can access?

Comment: You should use JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) like they suggested blow. Unless you need to use the array in a for loop, in which case, an associative array may not be a good choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode)

PHP:

```
$json_user = json_encode($user);
```

JavaScript:

```
var user = JSON.parse('<?php echo $json_user; ?>');
```

That's untested code but the idea behind it is sound

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried json_encode ?

```
<?php echo json_encode ( $array ); ?>
```

See the documentation [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).